# Sorting dictionary keys based on a value of the tuple associated with the key in swift

Tags: ios, sorting, dictionary, swift

I currently have a dictionary of type `[String: (Int, NSDate)]`. I would like to get an array of the keys (which are the strings in this case) sorted by the `NSDate` which is in the tuple.

So far, the best I could obtain is this code:

```
var ret = sorted(self.dictionary, {
  var tuple1 = $0.1 as (Int, NSDate)
  var tuple2 = $1.1 as (Int, NSDate)
  return tuple1.1.compare(tuple2.1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
})
```

But that returns something of the following type: `[(String, (Int, NSDate))`]

Is there an easy way for me to retrieve an array of strings only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ret = sorted(self.dictionary, ...)` returns an *array* of `(key,value)` tuples. You can 
extract the keys with

```
let keys = map(ret) { $0.0 }
```

Alternatively, sort the keys based on their values in the dictionary:

```
let keys = sorted(self.dictionary.keys) {
    (key1, key2) in
    let tuple1 = self.dictionary[key1]!
    let tuple2 = self.dictionary[key2]!
    return tuple1.1.compare(tuple2.1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```